# What do the two lines '||' in Kullback-Leibler Divergence mean?

Tags: statistics

I have just come across the Kullback-Leibler divergence in an article. This is the first time I am seeing it. What intrigued me are the two lines `'||'` in
  $ D_{KL}(P‖Q)$.    Below is the formulae.
[image]

I am not sure what they mean. Do they mean **'with respect to'**?

Can anyone kindly clarfiy this for me?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: They don't mean anything really, it's just a way to separate $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: That's it? :P Really hoped it would signify something else.

Comment: And to show it is non-commutative in $P,Q$ (in the way as $p(x|z)\ $ )

Comment: @reuns I am sorry I did not get that. Could you please elaborate on that point?

Comment: $D_{KL}(X\| Y) = \mathbb{E}_X[-\log \frac{p(X= x)}{p(Y=x)}]$.